# iOS 8 Draw outside of UITableViewCell bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

thats simple I want my UILabel inside `UITableViewCell` draw outside of cell bounds to overlap  `tableHeaderView`.

my tableViewView has only 1 row and tableHeaderView. I have not subclassed `UITableViewCell`

what I have done:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
[cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:NO];
[cell setClipsToBounds:NO];
}
```

but still cell clips its subview.

whats your idea?

[image]

Comment: I think the headerview overlap the cell.

Comment: you can't perform drawings or force elements to extend beyond the bounds of the uielement you are working with (this is part of Apple's core drawing concepts, there's no way around it that is safe, and I dont think theres a way around it period). If you want to overlap the header view, you are going to have to create some very intense custom logic to do this, and by intense I mean by not useing a header view and using a UILabel that responds to delegation events like a header would so the overlap is there.

Comment: @anhtu yeah thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@anhtu thanks for your hint. I just sent tableHeaderView to back which fixed the problem

```
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView.tableHeaderView];
```

Comment: Nice! Happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one cell and this label will appear only one time
put label outside the table view and put constrains for it